# Using forms with the Django outputs the token

Tags: python, django, token, csrf

I would really appreciate if you can give a hand with this.
What I'm trying to do it's just to render the value of some text label, but it gives me the token.

I'm learning django I hope you can comprehend.

The result of this is:

**eee 12121 csrfmiddlewaretoken yYvl3neQZSP33vSRNto3FUFa88AMeFQi**

view.

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        response = ''
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            response += '%s %s\n' % (key, value)

        return HttpResponse(response) 

    return render(request, 'datos2.html')
```

datos2.

```
<form action="/test" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="eee">
<input type="submit">
</form>


<p>ADD VALUE</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "0");
    x.setAttribute("name", "eee");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The problem is that django is not taking the add labels and I do not know how to make django take them. It only take the <input type="text" name="eee"> and not the others created dynamically :(

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over all the elements in the POST array in this snippet of code

```
for key, value in request.POST.items():
    response += '%s %s\n' % (key, value)
```

I believe, if i understand your question, that what you are after is simply `request.POST.get('eee')`

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer, if I get the value like you said works fine, the issue is that I need to add values, that's why I need to get all the elements.

Comment: Ah, your question makes a bit more sense with the comment you added to you question above. Two problems, first, the input elements you are dynamically creating in JS, are added to the body, not to the form. Secondly, are giving the dynamically create elements the same name 'eee'.